# How can i set chrome to use system titlebars and border in preferences file?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

i want chrome to use system titlebar and border as default. how can i do this with preferences file in $HOME/.config/google-chrome/Default/ directory?

Answer (score 13):

Open `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences`. It's a JSON file. The preference can be set by editing the following preference (I've only shown the relevant entries):

```
{ ...
   "browser": {
      ...
      "custom_chrome_frame": true,
      ...
```

- `true` - Hide system Title Bars and borders.
- `false` - Show system title bars and borders.

This preference only works on Linux, *not* on Windows, macOS or Chrome OS.
On macOS, the setting is `false`, on Windows and Chrome OS, the setting is `true` <sup>[ref](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/70af3549366e24509cf05e6903a8431ba8af037b)</sup>.

Comment: for windows `C:\Users\you\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences`

Comment: also, does not work anymore. If you add this setting and open chrome, it will show with the custom frames, and remove that line from the preferences file.

Comment: @gcb is correct, I can confirm that in the latest version of Chrome (Chrome 60) on Windows 7, this setting just gets deleted in Preferences if you try to add it, and it gets ignored. This might still work in Linux, I know some distros to this day that still show Chrome with a title bar. Various posts from experts on other forums also confirm that there is no way to do this on Windows.

Comment: @jrh This setting only works on Linux. I edited the answer to be more explicit about the supported platforms.

Answer (score 6):

For those living in the Google Chrome Version 41+:

1. Click the bars on the far right
2. Click Settings
3. Click "Use GTK Theme" and Check the "Use System Title and Borders"

[Dated, but still relevant Source](https://www.simplified.guide/chrome/hide-system-title-bar-in-kubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome 95, in Windows, you can have the system color the title bar based on whether it is active by selecting the "Default Color" theme.

Menu > Settings > Customize your Chrome profile > Default Color (top row, 2nd form left)

[image]