# Set Chrome to use system titlebars in windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Trying to find a way to do what the title says, I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505767/how-can-i-set-chrome-to-use-system-titlebars-and-border-in-preferences-file?newreg=904a301e84c144ad8e4a61f7a4626486) post, but it doesn't show a way to do it on Windows. A way to do it on Chrome or Chromium would both work, is this even possible or do I need linux?

If it doesn't work on Chrome, are there any other browsers that would allow me to force the system titlebar?

Comment: From the digging I've done, it seems it's not possible. It is, however, relatively simple to do with firefox: https://www.askvg.com/tip-force-firefox-to-always-use-system-titlebar-in-windows/